# How to add the newly added value to the state across mutations?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have this code:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
     bottles: 20,
     disabledBtn: false
    },
mutations: {
REMOVE_BOTTLES(state) {
  if (state.bottles > 0) {
    state.bottles--;
  }
},

ADD_BOTTLES(state, items) {
  state.bottles = state.bottles + items
  }   
},
actions: {
removeOneBottle ({commit}) {
  commit('REMOVE_BOTTLES');
},
addBottlesInput ({commit}, items) {
  commit('ADD_BOTTLES', items);
  }
 }
})
```

I need to add the newly added value to the state.
Here in the mutations it is simply added as a string, but I need it to add numbers that passed through the input. I would be grateful for any answer.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Your current mutations / actions only manipulate the `bottles` integer. What is it you're wanting to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your issue is that `items` is a string instead of a number, try changing your `ADD_BOTTLES` mutation to

```js
ADD_BOTTLES (state, items) {
  let num = parseInt(items, 10)
  if (!isNaN(num)) {
    state.bottles += items
  }
}
```

If you're getting the value from the user via a form, consider using the [`.number`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number) modifier. For example (based on your screenshot)...

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <p>How many bottles are there in total:</p>
    <p>{{ bottles }}</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>How many bottles of water were brought?</p>
    <input type="number" v-model.number="items" min="0">
    <button @click="addBottles(items)">Add</button>
  </section>
</template>
```

```js
import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data: () => ({ items: 0 }),
  computed: mapState(['bottles']),
  methods: mapMutations({
    addBottles: 'ADD_BOTTLES'
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, here is the link: (https://ibb.co/Jcky27L), when you click on the input and button, the state should change. That's what I want. Forgive me if I don't explain it that way.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not following what you're asking

Comment: Look (https://ibb.co/Jcky27L), when you u clicking "Add" button, I need to change state. Initial state was 20, and after clicking "Add" (for example 13), state has to be not 20, but 33

Comment: All you've shown is your store. Please edit your question to show what you're using to try and make those changes to the store. Also explain what problem you're having; how is it not working?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! My mistake was that I did not set `v-model.number = "items"`.